# Нужно изменить скрипт в зависимости от ширины экрана

Tags: javascript, css

Нужно сделать чтоб при ширине 375px выполнялась функция с другой высотой

```
 $(function(){
  $(".link").click(function(){ 
      $("#infoaboutApart").css({height: '800px'}); 
    });
  });

  $(function(){
  $(".link").click(function(){ 
      $(".info").css({height: '1700px'}); 
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут есть несколько вариантов. Можно попробовать через CSS, используя [медиа-запросы](https://webref.ru/css/value/media). Если принципиально js, то используем `window.innerWidth`. У Вас возможно допущена опечатка в коде, однако я сделал по вашим примерам.

**Итог:**

```
 $(function(){
  $(".link").on('click', function(){ 
      if(window.innerWidth < 376){
         $("#infoaboutApart").css({height: '800px'}); 
         $(".info").css({height: '1700px'}); 
      }else{
           //....
      }
    });
  });
```